# how to make a simple program on html5?

Tags: html, xhtml

I want to learn something new like html5, please guide me on html5 I do not have any idea on html5 coding but I have a background on basic html here are my questions.

1. What is the extension name of html5?
2. Is notepad++ will work on coding? or any suggestion?
3. Any site that teach basic html5 step by step.
4. Please give me example of html5 codes that showing Hello World in blue background.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You should try the Google Machine!!!  Seriously though, there are a lot of great tutorials out there.  Just type "HTML 5 tutorial" into the google search box.

Comment: I done that already, I'm just asking a little help for good suggestion if you don't mind. tnx anyway.

Comment: We shouldn't downvote questions like this.  The OP already went to google, they were asking for expert advice.  The OP is obviously a beginner so downvotes may be discouraging to them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML is not a ["programming language"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_language) but rather a ["mark-up" language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markup_language).  HTML5 is more than HTML though (it is the broader set of technologies including JavaScript and CSS).  I would suggest becoming familiar with the sites I'm listing below.  There you will find a number of good resources for learning HTML5.

- [HTML5 Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/default.asp) --> [HTML5 Tutorial Intro](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/html5_intro.asp)
- [HTML5 Rocks](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/) --> [HTML5 Rocks slides](http://slides.html5rocks.com/#landing-slide)
- [HTML5 Boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/)